# how can i unbind an emberjs handlebar helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a custom handlebar helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('foo', function(key) {
    return (key + ' bar');
});
```

and in my html I have:

```
{{foo beer}}
```

the result is

```
<div id="ember127" class="ember-view">beer bar</div>
```

how can I make my own handlebar helper act like the ember {{unbound beer}} and just produce "beer bar" without any additional markup ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I think you might be confused on how the helpers, templates, and Ember views work exactly. The markup you created is expected and is the exact markup you'd get with a working unbound helper.

Ember.Handlebars templates are always placed within an Ember view object (as you have above). Something that a normal bound helper would produce would be:

```
<div id="ember127" class="ember-view">
  <script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
      beer bar
  <script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</div>
```

Now if you want to surround your string with some other tag than a div (lets say an anchor tag or something), then you'd need to create a view, set it's template and tag name, then append that view.

Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/8mcZN/) and take a look at the results pane in your inspector for some examples of what I'm talking about. Hope that clears things up for you.

Comment: Thanks UD the Fiddle was great - I suppose i expected ember to be clever enough to work out that if it was unbound it didn’t require the extra markup.

Answer (score 5):

Ember [has a helper called `unbound`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/unbound.js) that lets you wrap another helper. You can thus turn your bound (automatically) `foo` helper into an unbound one like so

```
{{unbound foo beer}}
```